# Ability to change to address when sending email in python Tkinter

Tags: python, email, tkinter

I am a beginner in Python and with the help of kind Stackoverflow developers, I managed to build the below.

It is a random meeting host selector. You basically select a forum and select a type of engineer and it will randomly select an engineer to host a meeting.

Problem: I need help with the email portion. How do you send the email when the person's name is selected? It needs to be able to update the toaddr with the email from the dropdown list. The email body must also say "Hi [name], You are the host for the next [Select Forum] whereas currently, it says "Hi .!label3, You are the meeting chair for the next None"

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import datetime
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

root = Tk()
root.title('Random User Entry')
root.geometry("550x600")
root.configure(borderwidth="1")
root.configure(relief="sunken")
root.configure(cursor="arrow")
root.configure(highlightbackground="white")
root.configure(highlightcolor="black")

# f = forum, e = engineers
f = IntVar()
e = IntVar()


# Forums
networkcore = ['Tom Reeves', 'Joe Soap', 'John Smith', 'David Jones','Michael Johnson','Chris Lee']
security = ['Raven Kyle', 'Billy Joel','James Gonzalez','Maria Lopez','Justin Bright', 'Ali Baba']
unifiedcomms = ['Mary White', 'John Smith','Mike Brown','Mark Williams','Paul Rodriguez','Daniel Garcia']
designreview = ["Dave Brazel", "Gwendolyn Vogue", "Nikole Eaves", "Gaye Mccune", "Maricela Chance", "Bret Hazelip"]
automation = ["Renna Geeter", "Ken Stotz", "Nenita Penaflor", "Delena Lumpkins", "Jacqui Noles", "Chau Wardla"]
cloud = ["Nina Perea", "Lila Frederickson", "Brooks Baskette", "Esperanza Slavin","Elisa Duplantis"]


# un = username | eng = engineer
junior_eng_un = ['Raven Kyle', 'Billy Joel','James Gonzalez','Maria Lopez', 'Justin Bright', 'Ali Baba','Tom Reeves',
         'Joe Soap', 'John Smith', 'Mary White', 'John Smith','Mike Brown','Mark, Williams','Paul Rodriguez',
         'Daniel Garcia', "Dave Brazel", "Gwendolyn Vogue", "Nikole Eaves",
         "Gaye Mccune","Maricela Chance", "Bret Hazelip"]

senior_eng_un = ['David Jones','Michael Johnson','Chris Lee','Mary White', 'John Smith','Mike Brown','Mark Williams',
         'Paul Rodriguez','Daniel Garcia', "Nina Perea", "Lila Frederickson" , "Brooks Baskette",
         "Esperanza Slavin" ,"Elisa Duplantis"]


def tick():
datenow = datetime.datetime.now()
time_string = datenow.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%p")
clock.config(text=time_string)
clock.after(200, tick)


clock = Label(root, font=("times", 12, "bold"), fg="black", bg="lightgrey")
clock.grid(row=9, column=1, pady=3, padx=20, sticky=NW)
tick()


def update_engineer_list():
global engineers
forum = f.get()
engineer_group = e.get()
if forum and engineer_group:
# both forum and engineer group are selected
forum_engineers = networkcore if forum == 1 else security if forum == 2 else unifiedcomms if forum == 3 \
    else designreview if forum == 4 else automation if forum == 5 else cloud
# get available engineers for the selected forum
if engineer_group == 1:  # Junior
    engineers = [engineer for engineer in junior_eng_un if engineer in forum_engineers]
elif engineer_group == 2:  # Senior
    engineers = [engineer for engineer in senior_eng_un if engineer in forum_engineers]
elif engineer_group == 3:  # all
    engineers = forum_engineers
# update engineer list
engineer_list.config(state=NORMAL)
engineer_list.delete(1.0, END)
engineer_list.insert(END, "\n".join(sorted(engineers)))
engineer_list.config(state=DISABLED)
# clear host engineer
host_engineer["text"] = "Busy Randomising!!"


def choose_host():
# extract the engineer list from the engineer selection box
engineers = engineer_list.get(1.0, "end-1c").split("\n")
# then select one of them randomly
host_engineer["text"] = random.choice(engineers)


def clear_fields():
engineer_list.config(state=NORMAL)
engineer_list.delete(1.0, END)
host_engineer["text"] = ""
return()


def list_email_addr():
email_label = Label(root, text=clicked.get(), font="Helvetica 10 bold",fg="blue")
email_label.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=12, pady=3, sticky=NW)


email_options = ['Click Select Email Address:', "Maria.Lopez@gmail.com",'Raven.Kyle@gmail.com',
         'Billy.Joel@gmail.com','James.Gonzalez@gmail.com' ]
clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set(email_options[0])
email_label_drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked, *email_options)
email_label_drop.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=12, pady=3, sticky=NW)


def email_reminder():
# Need to actual from and to address
fromaddr = "abc@abc.com"
toaddr = "def@def.com"
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "Meeting Host Reminder "
body = "Hi " + str(host_engineer) + ", You are the meeting chair for the next " + str(update_engineer_list())
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
# Need to actual domain
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtpmail.domain.com', 25)
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
return ()


topLabel = Label(root, text="Random Meeting Host Selector", font="Helvetica 20")
topLabel.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, pady=5, padx=20)

fb2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Security Forum", font="Helvetica 12",variable=f, value=2,command=update_engineer_list)
fb2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, sticky=W)
fb1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Networking Forum", font="Helvetica 12",variable=f, value=1,command=update_engineer_list)
fb1.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, sticky=W)
fb3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Unified Comms Forum", font="Helvetica 12",variable=f, value=3,command=update_engineer_list)
fb3.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, sticky=W)
fb4 = Radiobutton(root, text="Design Review Forum", font="Helvetica 12",variable=f, value=4,command=update_engineer_list)
fb4.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, sticky=W)
fb5 = Radiobutton(root, text="Automation Forum", font="Helvetica 12",variable=f, value=5, command=update_engineer_list)
fb5.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=10, sticky=W)
fb6 = Radiobutton(root, text="Cloud Forum", font="Helvetica 12", variable=f,value=6, command=update_engineer_list)
fb6.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=10, sticky=W)

eb1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Junior Engineers", font="Helvetica 12",variable=e, value=1, command=update_engineer_list)
eb1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, sticky=W)
eb2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Senior Engineers", font="Helvetica 12",variable=e, value=2, command=update_engineer_list)
eb2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, sticky=W)
eb3 = Radiobutton(root, text="All Engineers", font="Helvetica 12",variable=e, value=3, command=update_engineer_list)
eb3.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, sticky=W)

hostButton = Button(root, text="Select Next Meeting Host!", font="Helvetica 10 bold", fg="blue", command=choose_host)
hostButton.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=40, sticky=NW)

# engineer list for selection
engineer_list = Text(root, width=30, height=20, bg="lightblue",font="Helvetica 10 bold", relief=SUNKEN, state=DISABLED)
engineer_list.grid(row=7, column=1, padx=10, pady=1, sticky=E)

# host engineer chosen
host_engineer = Label(root, width=20, height=2, bg="lightgreen", font="Helvetica 14 bold", bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
host_engineer.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=10, pady=33, sticky=N)

emailButton = Button(root, text="Click to Send Email Reminder", font="Helvetica 10 bold", command=email_reminder)
emailButton.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=14, pady=3, sticky=NW)

clearButton = Button(root, text="Clear Selections!", font="Helvetica 10", fg="red", command=clear_fields)
clearButton.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=14, pady=2, sticky=NW)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to change your program as little as possible. To answer the first part of your question concerning the host name label field, tkinter uses a dictionary structure to store attributes of widgets. You thus need to use host_engineer['text'] to retrieve the text on the label widget.

Since you said you are new to Python I really recommend reading about lists and dictionaries. Dictionaries are very useful, but be careful when you loop through them, the order is not guaranteed!

For this reason I added a list of "forum names" to use as keys to a dictionary of users in each forum. This brings me to the second part of your question. Since the order of list is fixed it allows us to used the list when creating the radio-buttons on the user interface which in turn makes it possible to use the value of the selected radio-button as an index to look up the selected forum name. The name can then be used as the key in the forum_users dictionary.

The same changes can be done for the engineering groups, but as I said I tried to keep as much of your code as possible.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import datetime
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

root = Tk()
root.title('Random User Entry')
root.geometry("550x600")
root.configure(borderwidth="1")
root.configure(relief="sunken")
root.configure(cursor="arrow")
root.configure(highlightbackground="white")
root.configure(highlightcolor="black")

# f = forum, e = engineers
f = IntVar()
e = IntVar()

# list of forum names in the order to be displayed
forum_names = ["Security Forum","Networking Forum","Unified Comms Forum","Design Review Forum","Automation Forum","Cloud Forum"]

# Forums
forum_users = {}
forum_users["Networking Forum"] = ['Tom Reeves', 'Joe Soap', 'John Smith', 'David Jones','Michael Johnson','Chris Lee']
forum_users["Security Forum"] = ['Raven Kyle', 'Billy Joel','James Gonzalez','Maria Lopez','Justin Bright', 'Ali Baba']
forum_users["Unified Comms Forum"] = ['Mary White', 'John Smith','Mike Brown','Mark Williams','Paul Rodriguez','Daniel Garcia']
forum_users["Design Review Forum"] = ["Dave Brazel", "Gwendolyn Vogue", "Nikole Eaves", "Gaye Mccune", "Maricela Chance", "Bret Hazelip"]
forum_users["Automation Forum"] = ["Renna Geeter", "Ken Stotz", "Nenita Penaflor", "Delena Lumpkins", "Jacqui Noles", "Chau Wardla"]
forum_users["Cloud Forum"] = ["Nina Perea", "Lila Frederickson", "Brooks Baskette", "Esperanza Slavin","Elisa Duplantis"]


# un = username | eng = engineer
junior_eng_un = ['Raven Kyle', 'Billy Joel','James Gonzalez','Maria Lopez', 'Justin Bright', 'Ali Baba','Tom Reeves',
         'Joe Soap', 'John Smith', 'Mary White', 'John Smith','Mike Brown','Mark, Williams','Paul Rodriguez',
         'Daniel Garcia', "Dave Brazel", "Gwendolyn Vogue", "Nikole Eaves",
         "Gaye Mccune","Maricela Chance", "Bret Hazelip"]

senior_eng_un = ['David Jones','Michael Johnson','Chris Lee','Mary White', 'John Smith','Mike Brown','Mark Williams',
         'Paul Rodriguez','Daniel Garcia', "Nina Perea", "Lila Frederickson" , "Brooks Baskette",
         "Esperanza Slavin" ,"Elisa Duplantis"]


def tick():
    datenow = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_string = datenow.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%p")
    clock.config(text=time_string)
    clock.after(200, tick)


    clock = Label(root, font=("times", 12, "bold"), fg="black", bg="lightgrey")
    clock.grid(row=9, column=1, pady=3, padx=20, sticky=NW)
    tick()


def update_engineer_list():
    forum_row = f.get()
    engineer_group = e.get()

    # both forum and engineer group are selected
    if forum and engineer_group:
    
        #get forum users
        forum_engineers = forum_users[forum_names[forum_row-1]]

        # get available engineers for the selected forum
        if engineer_group == 1:  # Junior
            engineers = [engineer for engineer in junior_eng_un if engineer in forum_engineers]
        elif engineer_group == 2:  # Senior
            engineers = [engineer for engineer in senior_eng_un if engineer in forum_engineers]
        elif engineer_group == 3:  # all
            engineers = forum_engineers
        # update engineer list
        engineer_list.config(state=NORMAL)
        engineer_list.delete(1.0, END)
        engineer_list.insert(END, "\n".join(sorted(engineers)))
        engineer_list.config(state=DISABLED)
        # clear host engineer
        host_engineer["text"] = "Busy Randomising!!"


def choose_host():
    # extract the engineer list from the engineer selection box
    engineers = engineer_list.get(1.0, "end-1c").split("\n")
    # then select one of them randomly
    host_engineer["text"] = random.choice(engineers)


def clear_fields():
    engineer_list.config(state=NORMAL)
    engineer_list.delete(1.0, END)
    host_engineer["text"] = ""
    return()


def list_email_addr():
    email_label = Label(root, text=clicked.get(), font="Helvetica 10 bold",fg="blue")
    email_label.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=12, pady=3, sticky=NW)


    email_options = ['Click Select Email Address:', "Maria.Lopez@gmail.com",'Raven.Kyle@gmail.com',
             'Billy.Joel@gmail.com','James.Gonzalez@gmail.com' ]
    clicked = StringVar()
    clicked.set(email_options[0])
    email_label_drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked, *email_options)
    email_label_drop.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=12, pady=3, sticky=NW)


def email_reminder():
    # Need to actual from and to address
    fromaddr = "abc@abc.com"
    toaddr = "def@def.com"
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg['Subject'] = "Meeting Host Reminder "
    body = "Hi " + str(host_engineer['text']) + ", You are the meeting chair for the next " + forum_names[f.get()-1] + " meeting."
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    # Need to actual domain
    #server = smtplib.SMTP('smtpmail.domain.com', 25)
    text = msg.as_string()
    #server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    #server.quit()
    print(text)
    return ()


topLabel = Label(root, text="Random Meeting Host Selector", font="Helvetica 20")
topLabel.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, pady=5, padx=20)

fblist = []
for row, forum in enumerate(forum_names):
    fbtemp = Radiobutton(root, text=forum, font="Helvetica 12",variable=f, value=row+1,command=update_engineer_list)
    fbtemp.grid(row=row+1, column=0, padx=10, sticky=W)
    fblist.append(fbtemp)

eb1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Junior Engineers", font="Helvetica 12",variable=e, value=1, command=update_engineer_list)
eb1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, sticky=W)
eb2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Senior Engineers", font="Helvetica 12",variable=e, value=2, command=update_engineer_list)
eb2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, sticky=W)
eb3 = Radiobutton(root, text="All Engineers", font="Helvetica 12",variable=e, value=3, command=update_engineer_list)
eb3.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, sticky=W)

hostButton = Button(root, text="Select Next Meeting Host!", font="Helvetica 10 bold", fg="blue", command=choose_host)
hostButton.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=40, sticky=NW)

# engineer list for selection
engineer_list = Text(root, width=30, height=20, bg="lightblue",font="Helvetica 10 bold", relief=SUNKEN, state=DISABLED)
engineer_list.grid(row=7, column=1, padx=10, pady=1, sticky=E)

# host engineer chosen
host_engineer = Label(root, width=20, height=2, bg="lightgreen", font="Helvetica 14 bold", bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
host_engineer.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=10, pady=33, sticky=N)

emailButton = Button(root, text="Click to Send Email Reminder", font="Helvetica 10 bold", command=email_reminder)
emailButton.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=14, pady=3, sticky=NW)

clearButton = Button(root, text="Clear Selections!", font="Helvetica 10", fg="red", command=clear_fields)
clearButton.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=14, pady=2, sticky=NW)

root.mainloop()
```

In terms of email addresses, you could create a dictionary which uses the username as the key and stores the email address as the values. Keep in mind that dictionary keys must be unique.

I would actually recommend that you rather create a small class object "user". Then the user name, email address, junior or senior, which forums they belong to, etc. can be attributes of the class. This would be a big change from your current code, but in the long run it will be much easier and clearer. If you are interested in seeing what it would look like see below:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import datetime
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

class User(object):
    """docstring for User"""
    def __init__(self, name, email, level, forums):
        super(User, self).__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.level = level
        self.forums = forums

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# list of forum names in the order to be displayed
forum_names = ["Security Forum","Networking Forum","Unified Comms Forum","Design Review Forum","Automation Forum","Cloud Forum"]
group_names = ["Junior Engineers","Senior Engineers","All Engineers"]

#NOTE: A person must be junior OR senior!

Users = []

#Juniors
Users.append(User('Raven Kyle','rkyle@gmail.com','Junior',["Security Forum",]))
Users.append(User('Billy Joel','bjoel@gmail.com','Junior',["Security Forum",]))
Users.append(User('James Gonzalez','jgon@gmail.com','Junior',["Security Forum",]))
Users.append(User('Maria Lopez','mlopes@gmail.com','Junior',["Security Forum","Automation Forum",]))
Users.append(User('Justin Bright','jbright@gmail.com','Junior',["Security Forum",]))
Users.append(User('Ali Baba','ababa@gmail.com','Junior',["Security Forum",]))
Users.append(User('Tom Reeves','treave@gmail.com','Junior',["Networking Forum",]))
Users.append(User('Joe Soap','jsoep@gmail.com','Junior',["Networking Forum",]))
Users.append(User('John Smith 1','jsmith1@gmail.com','Junior',["Networking Forum",]))
Users.append(User('John Smith 2','jsmith2@gmail.com','Junior',["Unified Comms Forum",]))
Users.append(User('Mike Brown','mbrown@gmail.com','Junior',["Unified Comms Forum","Automation Forum",]))
Users.append(User('Mark, Williams','mwill@gmail.com','Junior',["Unified Comms Forum",]))
Users.append(User("Dave Brazel",'dbra@gmail.com','Junior',["Design Review Forum",]))
Users.append(User("Gwendolyn Vogue",'gvogue@gmail.com','Junior',["Design Review Forum",]))
Users.append(User("Nikole Eaves",'neaves@gmail.com','Junior',["Design Review Forum",]))
Users.append(User("Gaye Mccune",'gmcc@gmail.com','Junior',["Design Review Forum",]))
Users.append(User("Maricela Chance",'mchance@gmail.com','Junior',["Design Review Forum",]))
Users.append(User("Bret Hazelip",'bhaze@gmail.com','Junior',["Design Review Forum","Cloud Forum",]))

#Seniors
Users.append(User('David Jones','dj@gmail.com','Senior',["Networking Forum",]))
Users.append(User('Michael Johnson','mjohnson@gmail.com','Senior',["Networking Forum",]))
Users.append(User('Chris Lee','clee@gmail.com','Senior',["Networking Forum",]))
Users.append(User('Mary White','mwhite@gmail.com','Senior',["Unified Comms Forum",]))
Users.append(User('John Smith 3','js3@gmail.com','Senior',["Unified Comms Forum",]))
Users.append(User('Mike Brown','mbrown@gmail.com','Senior',["Unified Comms Forum",]))
Users.append(User('Paul Rodriguez','prod@gmail.com','Senior',["Unified Comms Forum","Automation Forum",]))
Users.append(User('Daniel Garcia','dgarcia@gmail.com','Senior',["Unified Comms Forum",]))
Users.append(User("Nina Perea",'ninap@gmail.com','Senior',["Design Review Forum","Cloud Forum","Automation Forum",]))
Users.append(User("Lila Frederickson",'lilaf@gmail.com','Senior',["Cloud Forum",]))
Users.append(User("Brooks Baskette",'bbas@gmail.com','Senior',["Cloud Forum",]))
Users.append(User("Esperanza Slavin",'eslavin@gmail.com','Senior',["Cloud Forum",]))
Users.append(User("Elisa Duplantis",'edup@gmail.com','Senior',["Cloud Forum","Automation Forum",]))

#return all users that match the forum and level
def getForumUsers(forum, level):
    forum_users = []

    for user in Users:
        if forum in user.forums:
            if level.startswith('All') or level.startswith(user.level):
                forum_users.append(user)

    return forum_users

#find user object with given name
def findUser(name):
    for user in Users:
        if user.name == name:
            return user

#get the selected forum and level
def getForumAndLevel():
    f = selected_forum.get()
    g = selected_group.get()

    if f > 0 and g > 0:
        return forum_names[f-1], group_names[g-1]

    return None, None

def update_engineer_list():
    forum, level = getForumAndLevel()

    #check if both forum and group is selected
    if forum and level:
        # update engineer list
        engineer_list.config(state=NORMAL)
        engineer_list.delete(1.0, END)
        engineer_list.insert(END, "\n".join(sorted(str(usr) for usr in getForumUsers(forum, level))))
        engineer_list.config(state=DISABLED)
        # clear host engineer
        host_engineer["text"] = "Busy Randomising!!"

def choose_host():
    # extract the engineer list from the engineer selection box
    engineers = engineer_list.get(1.0, "end-1c").split("\n")
    # then select one of them randomly
    host_engineer["text"] = random.choice(engineers)

def clear_fields():
    engineer_list.config(state=NORMAL)
    engineer_list.delete(1.0, END)
    host_engineer["text"] = ""
    return()

def email_reminder():
    #get the host and forum details
    host_user = findUser(host_engineer['text'])
    forum, level = getForumAndLevel()

    if forum and level and host_user:
        # Need to actual from and to address
        fromaddr = "meetinggenerator@abc.com"
        toaddr = host_user.email
        ccaddr =  ", ".join(usr.email for usr in getForumUsers(forum, level) if usr != host_user)
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = fromaddr
        msg['To'] = toaddr
        msg['Cc'] = ccaddr
        msg['Subject'] = "Meeting Host Reminder "
        body = "Hi " + str(host_user) + ", You are the meeting chair for the next " + forum + " meeting."
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
        # Need to actual domain
        #server = smtplib.SMTP('smtpmail.domain.com', 25)
        text = msg.as_string()
        #server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
        #server.quit()
        print(text)
        clear_fields()

root = Tk()
root.title('Random User Entry')
root.geometry("550x600")
root.configure(borderwidth="1")
root.configure(relief="sunken")
root.configure(cursor="arrow")
root.configure(highlightbackground="white")
root.configure(highlightcolor="black")

topLabel = Label(root, text="Random Meeting Host Selector", font="Helvetica 20")
topLabel.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, pady=5, padx=20)

#tkinter requires that we keep a referance to all the widgets
widgetlist = []

selected_forum = IntVar()
selected_group = IntVar()

for count, forum in enumerate(forum_names):
    fb_temp = Radiobutton(root, text=forum, font="Helvetica 12",variable=selected_forum, value=count+1,command=update_engineer_list)
    fb_temp.grid(row=count+1, column=0, padx=10, sticky=W)
    widgetlist.append(fb_temp)

for count, group in enumerate(group_names):
    eb_temp = Radiobutton(root, text=group, font="Helvetica 12",variable=selected_group, value=count+1, command=update_engineer_list)
    eb_temp.grid(row=count+1, column=1, padx=10, sticky=W)
    widgetlist.append(eb_temp)

hostButton = Button(root, text="Select Next Meeting Host!", font="Helvetica 10 bold", fg="blue", command=choose_host)
hostButton.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=40, sticky=NW)

# engineer list for selection
engineer_list = Text(root, width=30, height=20, bg="lightblue",font="Helvetica 10 bold", relief=SUNKEN, state=DISABLED)
engineer_list.grid(row=7, column=1, padx=10, pady=1, sticky=E)

# host engineer chosen
host_engineer = Label(root, width=20, height=2, bg="lightgreen", font="Helvetica 14 bold", bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
host_engineer.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=10, pady=33, sticky=N)

emailButton = Button(root, text="Click to Send Email Reminder", font="Helvetica 10 bold", command=email_reminder)
emailButton.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=14, pady=3, sticky=NW)

clearButton = Button(root, text="Clear Selections!", font="Helvetica 10", fg="red", command=clear_fields)
clearButton.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=14, pady=2, sticky=NW)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank You So Much @SuzukiBKing. You understood what I needed and resolved the issue. I would definitely take your advice on leaning more on Dictionaries and Lists. I'm going through the code now trying to understand the changes as its very different from the original. Thank You again. All the Best!

Comment: Thank you again. I went through the code and understand it clearly now. It does make much sense and simpler to use Classes. The problem now is the 'cc emails are not getting through to the recipients.

Comment: Hi. Glad I could help. I can't test it now, but I've edited the answer to change the line "msg['CC'] = ccaddr" to "msg['Cc'] = ccaddr" which should solve your cc problem

Comment: Thank you. I tried and it doesn't work. I searched online and it says we need to add this as well "server.sendmail(fromaddr, (toaddr+ccaddr), text)"  but still didnt work. Error now is -  raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs) smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {abc@gmail.com')}

Comment: Are all the email addresses valid? Are you able to send messages without the the CC field? Try replacing `ccaddr = ";".join` with `ccaddr = ", ".join`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: when the script is executed it does print the CC address, however, mail doesn't come through. MIME-Version: 1.0
From: abc@gmail.com
To: WJ@gmail.com
Cc: DG@gmail.com;MG@gmail.com;ZN@gmail.com;TD@gmail.com
Subject: GNC Meeting Host Reminder 

--===============2128051415==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hi W, 

You are the meeting chair for the next Unified Comms Forum meeting.
--===============2128051415==--

Comment: From the error description you posted it seems not to like 'abc@gmail.com'. Have you tried with valid email addresses? How many people are you sending to? Did you change the ";"?

Comment: From what I read online the SMTPRecipientsRefused is raised if the addresses are not valid. **You need to change the semicolon to a comma**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219675/discussion-between-dillon-and-suzukibking).

Answer (score 1):

For the emails, you can do the following:

- Create a dictionary of name > email. This assumes all names are unique
- When you set the engineer text, store the engineer email
- When you send the email, use the stored email address and split the name to get the first name
- For the forum name, just create an array of names and use the f variable to select the index

Here is the updated code. Note that I created a list of fake emails based on the names. You will need to create this list manually.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import datetime
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

root = Tk()
root.title('Random User Entry')
root.geometry("550x600")
root.configure(borderwidth="1")
root.configure(relief="sunken")
root.configure(cursor="arrow")
root.configure(highlightbackground="white")
root.configure(highlightcolor="black")

# f = forum, e = engineers
f = IntVar()
e = IntVar()

# Forums
networkcore = ['Tom Reeves', 'Joe Soap', 'John Smith', 'David Jones','Michael Johnson','Chris Lee']
security = ['Raven Kyle', 'Billy Joel','James Gonzalez','Maria Lopez','Justin Bright', 'Ali Baba']
unifiedcomms = ['Mary White', 'John Smith','Mike Brown','Mark Williams','Paul Rodriguez','Daniel Garcia']
designreview = ["Dave Brazel", "Gwendolyn Vogue", "Nikole Eaves", "Gaye Mccune", "Maricela Chance", "Bret Hazelip"]
automation = ["Renna Geeter", "Ken Stotz", "Nenita Penaflor", "Delena Lumpkins", "Jacqui Noles", "Chau Wardla"]
cloud = ["Nina Perea", "Lila Frederickson", "Brooks Baskette", "Esperanza Slavin","Elisa Duplantis"]

# un = username | eng = engineer
junior_eng_un = ['Raven Kyle', 'Billy Joel','James Gonzalez','Maria Lopez', 'Justin Bright', 'Ali Baba','Tom Reeves',
         'Joe Soap', 'John Smith', 'Mary White', 'John Smith','Mike Brown','Mark, Williams','Paul Rodriguez',
         'Daniel Garcia', "Dave Brazel", "Gwendolyn Vogue", "Nikole Eaves",
         "Gaye Mccune","Maricela Chance", "Bret Hazelip"]

senior_eng_un = ['David Jones','Michael Johnson','Chris Lee','Mary White', 'John Smith','Mike Brown','Mark Williams',
         'Paul Rodriguez','Daniel Garcia', "Nina Perea", "Lila Frederickson" , "Brooks Baskette",
         "Esperanza Slavin" ,"Elisa Duplantis"]


# generate fake email dictionary, assumes all names are unique
emaillist = {}  # will be dictionary of names >  name:email
for lst in [networkcore,security,unifiedcomms,designreview,automation,cloud]:  # all names
    for nm in lst:
        emaillist[nm] = '.'.join(nm.split()) + '@gmail.com'  # map name to email

host_email = ""  # for email reminder


def tick():
    datenow = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_string = datenow.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%p")
    clock.config(text=time_string)
    clock.after(200, tick)


clock = Label(root, font=("times", 12, "bold"), fg="black", bg="lightgrey")
clock.grid(row=9, column=1, pady=3, padx=20, sticky=NW)
tick()


def update_engineer_list():
    global engineers
    forum = f.get()
    engineer_group = e.get()
    if forum and engineer_group:
        # both forum and engineer group are selected
        forum_engineers = networkcore if forum == 1 else security if forum == 2 else unifiedcomms if forum == 3 \
            else designreview if forum == 4 else automation if forum == 5 else cloud
        # get available engineers for the selected forum
        if engineer_group == 1:  # Junior
            engineers = [engineer for engineer in junior_eng_un if engineer in forum_engineers]
        elif engineer_group == 2:  # Senior
            engineers = [engineer for engineer in senior_eng_un if engineer in forum_engineers]
        elif engineer_group == 3:  # all
            engineers = forum_engineers
        # update engineer list
        engineer_list.config(state=NORMAL)
        engineer_list.delete(1.0, END)
        engineer_list.insert(END, "\n".join(sorted(engineers)))
        engineer_list.config(state=DISABLED)
        # clear host engineer
        host_engineer["text"] = "Busy Randomising!!"


def choose_host():
    global host_email
    # extract the engineer list from the engineer selection box
    engineers = engineer_list.get(1.0, "end-1c").split("\n")
    # then select one of them randomly
    host_engineer["text"] = random.choice(engineers)
    if host_engineer["text"] in emaillist:
        host_email = emaillist[host_engineer["text"]]  # for email reminder
    else:
        print("No email for '"+host_engineer["text"]+"'")


def clear_fields():
    engineer_list.config(state=NORMAL)
    engineer_list.delete(1.0, END)
    host_engineer["text"] = ""
    return()


def list_email_addr():
    email_label = Label(root, text=clicked.get(), font="Helvetica 10 bold",fg="blue")
    email_label.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=12, pady=3, sticky=NW)


email_options = ['Click Select Email Address:', "Maria.Lopez@gmail.com",'Raven.Kyle@gmail.com',
         'Billy.Joel@gmail.com','James.Gonzalez@gmail.com' ]
clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set(email_options[0])
email_label_drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked, *email_options)
email_label_drop.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=12, pady=3, sticky=NW)

def email_reminder():
    # get forum name
    flist = ['Networking Forum','Security Forum','Unified Comms Forum','Design Review Forum','Automation Forum','Cloud Forum']
    fname = flist[f.get()-1]
    
    # Need to actual from and to address
    fromaddr = "abc@abc.com"
    toaddr = host_email
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg['Subject'] = "Meeting Host Reminder "
    body = "Hi " + str(host_engineer["text"].split()[0]) + ", You are the meeting chair for the next " + fname
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    text = msg.as_string()
    print('Email msg:\n',text)
    # Need to actual domain
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtpmail.domain.com', 25)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    server.quit()
    return ()


topLabel = Label(root, text="Random Meeting Host Selector", font="Helvetica 20")
topLabel.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, pady=5, padx=20)

fb2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Security Forum", font="Helvetica 12",variable=f, value=2,command=update_engineer_list)
fb2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, sticky=W)
fb1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Networking Forum", font="Helvetica 12",variable=f, value=1,command=update_engineer_list)
fb1.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, sticky=W)
fb3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Unified Comms Forum", font="Helvetica 12",variable=f, value=3,command=update_engineer_list)
fb3.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, sticky=W)
fb4 = Radiobutton(root, text="Design Review Forum", font="Helvetica 12",variable=f, value=4,command=update_engineer_list)
fb4.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, sticky=W)
fb5 = Radiobutton(root, text="Automation Forum", font="Helvetica 12",variable=f, value=5, command=update_engineer_list)
fb5.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=10, sticky=W)
fb6 = Radiobutton(root, text="Cloud Forum", font="Helvetica 12", variable=f,value=6, command=update_engineer_list)
fb6.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=10, sticky=W)

eb1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Junior Engineers", font="Helvetica 12",variable=e, value=1, command=update_engineer_list)
eb1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, sticky=W)
eb2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Senior Engineers", font="Helvetica 12",variable=e, value=2, command=update_engineer_list)
eb2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, sticky=W)
eb3 = Radiobutton(root, text="All Engineers", font="Helvetica 12",variable=e, value=3, command=update_engineer_list)
eb3.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, sticky=W)

hostButton = Button(root, text="Select Next Meeting Host!", font="Helvetica 10 bold", fg="blue", command=choose_host)
hostButton.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=40, sticky=NW)

# engineer list for selection
engineer_list = Text(root, width=30, height=20, bg="lightblue",font="Helvetica 10 bold", relief=SUNKEN, state=DISABLED)
engineer_list.grid(row=7, column=1, padx=10, pady=1, sticky=E)

# host engineer chosen
host_engineer = Label(root, width=20, height=2, bg="lightgreen", font="Helvetica 14 bold", bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
host_engineer.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=10, pady=33, sticky=N)

emailButton = Button(root, text="Click to Send Email Reminder", font="Helvetica 10 bold", command=email_reminder)
emailButton.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=14, pady=3, sticky=NW)

clearButton = Button(root, text="Clear Selections!", font="Helvetica 10", fg="red", command=clear_fields)
clearButton.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=14, pady=2, sticky=NW)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank You So Much @Mike67. You understood what I needed and resolved the issue. I'm going through the code now trying to understand the changes as its very different from the original. Thank You again. All the Best!